# What is the jQuery OR JavaScript code for getting the height of an external element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Using the code below, I am successfully getting the jQuery.load to pull the external element's html into the div (`"tnc-import"`), but according the console, the `newElementHeight` variable just returns the init information of the element (`init [prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "div#tnc-import > div#tnc"]`) instead of actually getting the true-height attribute of the external element.

The source document includes the text to be imported inside `<div id="tnc">...</div>`.
 The target document includes...

```
<div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="/bin/tnc-import" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>`
```

The intermediary document doing the importing and formatting is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tnc-import"></div>
    </body>

    <foot>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $("#tnc-import").load( "../terms-and-conditions #tnc" );
            var newElementHeight = $("div#tnc-import > div#tnc").height(true);
            console.log(newElementHeight);
            $('#iframe', window.parent.document).width('100%');
            $('#iframe', window.parent.document).height(newElementHeight);
        </script>
    </foot>
</html>
```

The reason why I'm trying this is that all attempts to get the `height`, `clientHeight`, `offsetHeight`, etc of the jQuery-loaded element always result in "0". I've literally spent more than 12 hours troubleshooting with Google on this one objective, but with no positive result. Perhaps there is something wrong with that script that I've just not noticed... Either way, neither method or any variation that I've tried has worked.

Here is one of the old method variants that I was trying...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#iframe', window.parent.document).width('100%');
    $('#iframe', window.parent.document).height($("div").outerHeight() + 10);
</script>
```

Comment: This question is not yet answered... anyone else willing to try?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of jQuery, `.height()` does not accept any arguments with Boolean parameters, try removing true from the function to receive height in  `newElementHeight` element.

Reference :http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Unfortunately, `newElementHeight` results in "null" after removing "true" from the `.height()` function.

Comment: Yeah thats because there is no div inside the `id="tnc-import"` your selector is wrong.

Comment: Instead of `$("div#tnc-import > div#tnc")` try `$("div#tnc-import")`

Comment: Adding that change now makes `newElementHeight` result in "0".